# Why Does The `auto_update_plugin` Hook Disable Management?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm working with the [`auto_update_plugin`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/auto_update_type/) to update active plugins on a specific schedule. If the current time is between X and Y then the filter returns true and the plugin is allowed to auto-update.

The problem I'm running into with this hook is that the return value either enables or disables update management entirely. This means that by returning `true` I am unable to disable updates for a specific plugin as the "Automatic Updates" link is removed and replaced with text.

Why does this happen?

Is there a better hook to allow users to manage which plugins should auto-update while also being able to filter when it should auto-update?

Comment: Did you check the 2nd parameter of the hook provides?

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm not sure it matters. The problem is that by using the filter it removes the ability to enable/disable updates for any specific plugin. The end result I'm going for is to allow Admins to enable auto-updates for specific plugins, then use the above filter to allow any auto-update enabled plugins to update between a specific timeframe.

Comment: But if you have the item it's checking you can inspect it and if it's a plugin you want to force to update, you can force it, otherwise return the value you were passed. I think that flawed assumption here is that if there are 5 plugins to update, it gets called 5 times, once for each plugin, but you've assumed it's a global filter that gets called only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root problem here is a misunderstanding of the appropriate hook. `auto_update_plugin` does not control if automatic updates are enabled, but rather it's a filter to gain finer control over wether a specific plugin should auto update a specific update.

For example, if you want to enable or disable wether plugin auto-updating is possible, use the `plugins_auto_update_enabled` filter.

If you want to override a plugin and force it to auto-update or not update, use `auto_update_plugin` and inspect the second parameter, the format of which matches what the .org API at https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/update-check/1.1/ would return